# Question about the answer to a root of a complex number.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers

I am supposed to solve for the roots of the complex number $(2(\cos(\pi/3)+i\sin(\pi/3))^{\frac{1}{2}}$.

The answer I get is that the roots are $\sqrt2e^{i\frac{\pi}{6}}$ and $\sqrt2e^{i\frac{7\pi}{6}}$. However, the answer key says that the roots are $\frac{\sqrt3+i}{\sqrt2}$and $-\frac{\sqrt3+i}{\sqrt2}$. Why is this?

Doesn't $(2(\cos(\pi/3)+i\sin(\pi/3))^{\frac{1}{2}}=1+\sqrt(3)i$, where did the answer key get (sqrt(3)+i) from?
(Images attached below)

[image: Problem] [image: My Answer]

Comment: They may have computed the sine and cosine of $\pi/6, 5\pi/6$ and placed them where they go.

Comment: I've converted the first equation to latex format, could you look at what I've done and try to copy that for the rest of the equations?

Comment: Yeah sure, I didn't know you could write latex in this, whoops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've lost a $2$ in divisor. Roots are
$\sqrt{2}e^{i\pi/6}$ and $\sqrt{2}e^{i7\pi/6}=\sqrt{2}e^{-i5\pi/6}$

Which are
$$\pm\frac{\sqrt{3}+i}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Comment: Ah, thanks for catching that. So my answers are right, just that they're not converted to the form in the answer key.

Comment: I'd also recommend you to use dash to better distinguish 7 from 1. But just an advice